# Libreoffice convert-to set outfile name

Tags: libreoffice

I'm trying to convert a file with libreoffice, but I know I can use the `-outdir` but that puts in a directory, is there any way to have it actually output the filename as I suggest?

Currently I'm using this command

```
libreoffice --convert-to pdf -outdir outfile pdf filename
```

But this puts the file inside outfile directory and then it puts a file inside that directory